# For Loop for slicing dataframes based on times from another dataframe

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, dataframe

I have created a df with start and end times. However they are in strings and need them in datetime formats. Below is the code I have written

```
import dateutil.parser as date_parser
start_time = df_gt['start_time']
end_time = df_gt['end_time']

for i in start_time:
    datetime = date_parser.parse(i)
    print(datetime)

2017-10-04 10:45:08
2017-10-04 10:47:31
2017-10-04 10:47:51
2017-10-04 10:49:43
```

Ideal output would be datatimes with just 10:49:43 times.

Problem with the output is i dont want the date 2017-10-04 in the output. Can anyone tell me how to set the parameters to just make it convert the string to datetime? or show me a page with the knowledge?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: not yet i will though, thank you

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: the times are a string within the dataframe under the start_time column and end_time columns

Comment: you mean adding the pd.to_date after i convert the string to a datetime format?

Comment: In my answer, `series` is a column of strings.